# Kivy CheckBox Looks Like Solid Black Box (Not a Checkbox)

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a BoxLayout widget (orientation = 'horizontal') that contains three widgets inside of it, a label, a text box, and a check box.

```
thisRow = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
l = Label(text='Enter plate 1:\n(Plate #)')
t = TextInput(text = 'this is a text box')
c = CheckBox()
thisRow.add_widget(l)
thisRow.add_widget(t)
thisRow.add_widget(c)
```

This produces the following widget (thisRow):

[image]

After the box is checked...

[image]

The rightmost black box is actually the checkbox, and works functionally, however there is no way for the user to know that it is in fact a checkbox. I would expect a smaller empty square in the middle, as is depicted in pictures [here.](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html)

How do i get the traditional checkbox image (smaller empty square box)? Or generally, how can I make it more obvious that the box is a check box and not just an empty label?

Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is that the checkbox is being resized to fill the entire box. What you want is another container that allows the checkbox to retain its natural size and float in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

This is really interesting question and Malonge tried it in a good way. Right now(1.9.2-dev) there is still fixed size on `CheckBox`'s well, call it a background. It's an image that `Widget` takes from atlas and changes if the state changes. Therefore until [now](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4266) there was no clear way how to do it. Here is an example. Soon on master there'll be `CheckBox(color=[r,g,b,a])` option. Thanks ;)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<CheckBoxBG>:
    Label:
    TextInput:
    CheckBox:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,0,0
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
                size:[16,16]
            Color:
                rgb: 0,0,0
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.center_x-7, self.center_y-7
                size:[14,14]
''')
class CheckBoxBG(BoxLayout):pass
runTouchApp(CheckBoxBG())
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the smaller check box is hidden when the background color is black. Here is an example of a red background.

[image]

It's not ideal because I do like the black background, but I can run with it for now. If anyone knows how to do this with a black background that would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to change your checkboxes background, you can use another image from the atlas or create images and then load them:

```
mycheckbox= CheckBox(
background_checkbox_normal ='tlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_disabled'
background_checkbox_down = 'my_checkboxes_checked.png'
)
```

---

In  Kivy 1.9.2.dev0 (and apparently since version 1.9.0) you can change the background image of checkboxes. By default, Kivy uses for these backgrounds from the atlas*.

```
background_checkbox_normal = StringProperty('atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_off') #when the checkbox is not active.
background_checkbox_down = StringProperty('atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_on') # when the checkbox is active.
background_checkbox_disabled_normal = StringProperty('atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_disabled_off') #when the checkbox is disabled and not active.
background_checkbox_disabled_down = StringProperty('atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_disabled_on') #when the checkbox is disabled and active.
```

You can have a look [here](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/checkbox.html) at all the attributes :

*The atlas is a package of multiple textures that reduces the number of images loaded and speedup the application loading. You have see a preview of the atlas in `Python Install Folder\Lib\site-packages\kivy\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png`