# Kivy: how to use canvas for widgets created in python

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I would like to add a canvas to my checkboxes to change their color. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072458/3154274), but I am struggling to implement it. 
My checkboxes are created in python with this code:

```
checkb= CheckBox()
layout.add_widget(checkb)
```

Attempt 1: I tried the solution from [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas) but without success:

```
checkb= CheckBox()
checkb.canvas.add(Color(1., 1., 0))
checkb.canvas.add(Rectangle(size=(50, 50)))
layout.add_widget(checkb)
```

Attempt 2: I also tried to come up with a custom checkbox created in the builder but didn't find a way to make it work (I couldn't find any info about this kind of setup, so I am not sure it's even possible to make it work):

```
Builder.load_string('''
<CustomCk@CheckBox>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
            size:[16,16]
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x-7, self.center_y-7
            size:[14,14]                

''')
```

and

```
checkb= CustomCk()
layout.add_widget(checkb)
```

---

Edit : my try with the with statement:

```
checkb= CheckBox()  
with checkb.canvas:
    Color(1, 2, 0)
    Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
layout.add_widget(checkb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **with** statement from your python code

```
with checkb.canvas:
    Color(1., 1., 0)
    Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
```

Your other approach seems better, just fix it a bit:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<CustomCk>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
            size:[16,16]
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x-7, self.center_y-7
            size:[14,14]                

    ''')

class CustomCk(CheckBox): #define the class in the python file... 
     pass

checkb= CustomCk()
layout.add_widget(checkb)
```

Comment: I tried the `with` statement (cf the edit in my question) but the background remains the same. Any idea why?

Comment: In the **kv** example you also have the **pos** binded to the center of the CheckBox, try to do the same in the **with** example (You'll also need to *bind* the checkbox.center)