# Kivy Custom Button on_press change canvas colour

Tags: python, kivy

Further to my last question, I have been looking at the documentation and online for examples for how to change the canvas color of a custom button on press. Here is what I have; nothing changes when clicked:

```
class CircularButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    # code inspired from:
        # https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4263#issuecomment-217430358
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42886979/6924364
        # https://blog.kivy.org/2014/10/updating-canvas-instructions-declared-in-python/

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircularButton,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=(.5,.5,.5,.5))
            self.shape = Ellipse(pos=self.pos,size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_shape, size=self.update_shape)

    def update_shape(self, *args):
        self.shape.pos = self.pos
        self.shape.size = self.size

    def on_press(self, *args): #<--- what am I doing wrong here?
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=(0,0,0,0))

    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        return Vector(x, y).distance(self.center) <= self.width / 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to store and reuse the Color instruction and change the color as Canvas adds the instructions, in your case you are adding a new Color instruction that does not apply to another element like Rectangle or Ellipse so you do not see the effect.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class CircularButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    background_color = ListProperty((0.5,.5,.5,.5))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircularButton,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.draw()
        self.text='test'

    def update_shape(self, *args):
        self.shape.pos = self.pos
        self.shape.size = self.size

    def on_background_color(self, *args):
        self.shape_color.rgba = self.background_color

    def draw(self, *args):
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.shape_color = Color(rgba=(0.5,.5,.5,.5))
            self.shape = Ellipse(pos=self.pos,size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_shape, size=self.update_shape)

    def on_press(self, *args):
        self.background_color= (1, 0, 0, 1)

    def on_release(self, *arg):
        self.background_color = (0.5,.5,.5,.5)

    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        return Vector(x, y).distance(self.center) <= self.width / 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(CircularButton())
```

Although I prefer to combine the .kv and the .py taking advantage of the kv language is declarative making the connections are simple:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<CircularButton>
    background_color: 0.5,.5,.5,.5
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ''')


class CircularButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircularButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "test"

    def on_press(self, *args):
        self.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)

    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        return Vector(x, y).distance(self.center) <= self.width / 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(CircularButton())
```

Comment: Love it! I've tried adding the function `on_release` to reset the color back to `.5,.5,.5,.5` however it only dims the red rather than going back to gray. How come?

Comment: @Justapigeon try the second method, I will find out why the first method fails

Comment: interestingly, when I inspect the canvas, the color object's rgba value is 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 despite the assigned colours.

Comment: @Justapigeon I have updated my answer, is confused and thought that canvas eliminated the previous but it is not true, add it for what you have to reuse, I have already indicated in my updated answer, test returned and tell me if you still have the error.

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Comment: I have been searching for an answer to this exact same problem for a week! Thanks for taking the time to solve it for us.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe helps someone this solution:

.py

```
class PositionButton(Button):
    b_color = ListProperty()
```

.kv

```
<PositionButton>:
    background_color: [0,0,0,0]
    b_color: [0, 0, 1, .3] if self.state == 'normal' else [0, 0, 1, .5]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.b_color
```